# A Pair list with some equals key/values?

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I need a Pair list, with "string", "string".

Tried :

```
Dictionary<string, string> Categories= new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

but can't add "700", "2" and "700", "3". I need a Pair where I can add everythings, when I want. Like a Vector that can contain N Vector (string, string). Which structure I need? Quickly, because I need to compaire them in LINQ, after :

```
myStructs = from MyObject s in MyObjects
               join c in Categories on s.IDCategory.UniqueID equals c.Key
               join d in Categories on s.Stars equals d.Value
               select s;
```

Answer (score 9):

Try `List<Tuple<string, string>>`, or for increased readability, simply make a new type.

If you need it to make sense during linq, you could transfer the tuple into an anonymous type (using `let` here) to give the type some sensible property names:

```
var items = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
    {
        new Tuple<string, string>("Adam", "1"), 
        new Tuple<string, string>("Adam", "2")
    };

var names = from i in items
            let person = new { Name = i.Item1, Number = i.Item2 }
            select person.Name;
```

Makes it a little more readable during a linq query.

It the type is used a lot, I advise creating your own type with better property names for clarity as in [Servy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11525508/358221). In the long run, `Tuple<string, int, bool>` is *a lot less* obvious than:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool LikesCake { get; set; }
}
```

Tuple equality is based on the equality of all it's properties against an instance of the same type of tuple. For example, `new Tuple("Adam", "1").Equals(new Tuple("Adam", "1"))` will be true.

Lists also do not stop duplicate items. If you need to enforce uniqueness across all the properties, then `HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>` is what you need.

Comment: I like this. I wasn't sure what a Tuple was until I read this answer. Then I read a little further: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: @DaveDev Yeah I like tuple in small doses (as it becomes unreadable with Item1/2/3 everywhere all the time). It always makes me chuckle when you look at the docs link you provided, "How do we take variable numbers of arguments?" "We define 8 classes!" "God help us if they need a 9th..."

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth It can be done: `Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, Tuple<string, string>> nineDTuple;`  Or just do it entirely LISP style: `Tuple<string, Tuple<string, Tuple<string, Tuple<string, Tuple<string, Tuple<string, Tuple<string, Tuple<string, string>>>>>>>> nineDTuple2;`

Comment: @Servy I'd rather play Russian Roulette than read that code again ;-) I draw the line at a type having three closing angled brackets `>>>`.

Comment: A rule of thumb that I try to adhere to is that if I ever see myself writing code that appears like that, for whatever reason, I'm usually doing it wrong. In my experience when code looks like that, you're trying to dig yourself out of something.

Comment: @Servy Very true, I'm on the fence personally. If it is temporary or very local I tend towards Tuple, if it is important to be clear or is more public than local I tend towards a type. Just got to watch out for one of the two most complicated things in programming: naming things, you fast run out of names :-)

Comment: @DaveDev It was a joke.  I would never, ever, use code like that in a production app.

Comment: @Servy - I understand that, I wasn't criticizing you. Just pointing out my experience.

Comment: @Servy I didn't take it as a criticism, and ditto - my experience is slowly pushing me towards types or anonymous types as the days go on. A tuple with anything more than 3 items is just getting silly.

Comment: Your example `new Tuple("Adam", "1") == new Tuple("Adam", "1")` is incorrect. The class `Tuple<,>` does not change the meaning of the `==` operator, so this checks for reference equality! Use `Equals(Tuple.Create("Adam", "1"), Tuple.Create("Adam", "1"))` instead.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Rectified, I didn't actually mean to provide a literal C# code example, but obviously it is and that just confused my meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Just create your own.

```
public class Pair
{
  public string First {get;set;}
  public string Second {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can have a `List<Pair>` to hold your data.

There are several possible library classes that you could re-purpose for your own needs, but in particular if this pair actually represents something (meaning you'd rename the class and the properties to something more meaningful) then it can be useful to have it in its own class to denote that.  If you did want to just re-use an existing type then `Tuple<string,string>` would probably be the best choice.

Comment: The one thing to note on this over `Tuple<string, string>`, although much more readable it does not come with any decent equality logic out of the box, two instances of this will just be equal based on reference, not on content. That said, it is obviously straightforward to override this, just it doesn't come for free :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary` is a hashed location keys, so you cannot have duplicates in the dictionary. You could have a list of type `<string,string>` either by using a`KeyValuePair` or `Tuple`

Answer (score 0):

A `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` would probably work well if you're in .NET 3.5 or below, and if 4 or above, `List<Tuple<string, string>>` would be a winner.